# Send Data to HTML Template through Spring AOP?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-aop

I'd like to wrap all the controller methods using Spring AOP for Error Handling.

But, How to send e.getMessage() in catch block to ${errorMessage} in error.html properly?

Thanks for the response!

---

```
    @Pointcut("within(com.test.mvc.controller.*) && @within(org.springframework.stereotype.Controller)")
    public void controllerLayer() {
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(public String *(..))")
    public void publicMethod() {
    }

    @Pointcut("controllerLayer() && publicMethod()")
    public void controllerPublicMethod() {
    }

    @Around("controllerPublicMethod()")
    public String processRequest(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {

        try {

            return (String) joinPoint.proceed();

        } catch (Throwable e) {

            LOGGER.info("{}", e.getMessage());
            return "error.html";

        }

    }
```

---

```
<body>

        <h1>Something went wrong!</h1>
        <h3 th:text="'Error Message: ' + ${errorMessage}"></h3>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following aspect can set the request attribute to display errorMessage.

```
@Around("controllerPublicMethod()")
public Object processRequest(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
    Object object=null;
    try {
        object = joinPoint.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes().setAttribute("errorMessage",e.getMessage(),0); // scope 0 - request , 1 - session
        return "error.html";
    }
    return object;
}
```

I recommend you please explore the possibilities of [`@ControllerAdvice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html)